# Visual Studio 2015 Change target platform to windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

How can I change the target platform to Windows 7? All I can chose is Windows 8.1 and therefore my project does not run on Windows 7. The same project I used to compile on my old Windows 7 PC with Visual Studio 2013. And of course it worked there.

I already tried to install Windows 7 SDK but sadly this does not work since it requites Net Framework 4.0 which I can not install anymore.  (Windows 10 includes 4.6?) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ff770576.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: "therefore my project does not run on Windows 7" - are you sure about that?

Comment: On windows 7 ,I only have the choice for 8.1 (default) and two versions for 10 and build programs just work.

Comment: melak47: Yes I am trying to run it on a different PC with Windows 7. 
ixSci: http://prntscr.com/9obzgv Thats what I meant :)
HansPassant: I will try now. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @culi0x: what error are you getting? Have you installed the VC++ 2015 runtime on the other machine? Why have you selected the *Win XP* platform toolset?

Answer (score 32):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx):

> **Target Platform Version**
>
> [...]
>
> To target Windows 7 or Windows Vista, use the value 8.1, since Windows SDK 8.1 is backward compatible to those platforms. In addition, you should define the appropriate value for _WIN32_WINNT in targetver.h. For Windows 7, that's 0x0601. See [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

To get additional target platforms (i.e. older Visual C compilers), install the respective older Visual Studio version(s) in parallel.

For instance, if you want to use Visual Studio 2017 in the GUI and want to build against VC2008 (msvc90), install Visual Studio 2008 in parallel to Visual Studio 2017. In VS2017, in the build settings, you can then select the "VC 2008" build target.

Also see:
https://poweruser.blog/visual-studio-2017-compile-against-older-visual-c-c-runtimes-372519fe1400