# Visual C++ : Change target platform version to Windows 7

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, target-platform

Before building a project in Visual C++, when I check the target platform version, I only see 8.1. I cannot change that to 7, which is my target platform.
Here's a shot: [image: http://i.imgur.com/jH4XG9B.jpg]

For that, the directx project I'm building doesn't run succesfully. It seeks for such dlls (i.e: d3dcompiler_47.dll and others...) those are present in windows 8.1, but not In windows 7(windows 7 has d3dcompiler_33.dll to d3dcompiler_43.dll). I only get lots of dll missing errors.

I've also tried:
`#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7                   0x0601 //windows 7`
in the targetver.h file but nothing succesful. I wan't to build it for Windows 7 so that I can run it smoothly on 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.


**I'm using:**

1. Visual Studio 2015 Community with update 3
2. Windows 7 32-bit SP1
3. Windows 8.1 SDK which installed along with Visual Studio

   [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706246/visual-studio-2015-change-target-platform-to-windows-7) Didn't help me.

Comment: Changing the target platform isn't going to help one bit. You have a deployment issue here. See [Direct3D 11 Deployment for Game Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx) for information.

Comment: The `#define` line is also wrong. You meant to say `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` — the `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` is a symbolic name provided by Microsoft in the header files for a possible value of the real constant, which is `_WIN32_WINNT`. (You don't get a compiler error for defining `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` twice because C allows you to have two `#define`s that evaluate to the same replacement string. It's weird.) It also has to be *before* you include `<windows.h>` or any other system header.