# How can I use input parameter as a pass to the file?

Tags: c++

I'm a new to c++ and the task I'm currently trying to solve is to parse some data in *.txt file in one directory to the *+1.txt file in the other directory. 
I've used the sample of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
std::ifstream input("C:\\Tmp\\example.txt");
std::string outfilepass = "";
    outfilepass +=argv[2];
    outfilepass +="\\";
    outfilepass += argv[1];
std::ofstream outfile(outfilepass);
return 0;
}
```

If I compile it and then use 
sample.exe example1.txt "C:\Tmp\NewFolder\" everything is works fine in windows 10, but nothing happens in windows 7.

**!Update**

I've found some useful links that helped me to find the solution. Problem was in target platform for the application. (I've used VS 2019). Here are some useful links:

[Visual Studio 2015 Change target platform to windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706246/visual-studio-2015-change-target-platform-to-windows-7)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

Comment: Does `C:\Tmp` exist on your Windows 7 test machine and is it writable by the user?

Comment: In this respect the OS is no different. You should modify your code to complain if argc is less than 3. You should also complain if the file is not found or the directory is invalid.

Comment: After the line `std::ifstream input(...);` check if the file was opened ok. If it wasn't, do: `std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` instead of continuing as if everything worked fine. The same should be done after you've tried to  open `outfile`.

Comment: you also don't use input or write anything to the outfile. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Try to start your program with `C:/Tmp/NewFolder` instead of `C:\Tmp\NewFolder` or use `\\` to escape the backslashes.
Consider using the [<filesystem> APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/file-system-navigation?view=vs-2019) by Microsoft.

Also make sure that the Folder already exists and that you have write-access to the folder, as cdhowie said.

Comment: Note that there is really not much we can do to help you on this. Maybe you have to use your debugger on Windows 7 in addition to putting some error handling code in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some useful links that helped me to find the solution. Problem was in target platform for the application. (I've used VS 2019). Here are some useful links:

[Visual Studio 2015 Change target platform to windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706246/visual-studio-2015-change-target-platform-to-windows-7)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

The solution was build in release with

```
#define WINVER 0x0601 и _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```